# Mui Material CircularProgress Area

Tags: css, svg, material-ui, progress-bar, spinner

I am using this [official guide](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-progress/#customization) to make a facebook like spinner.

but the problem is that I want to reduce the blue(on top) CircularProgress's circle area(or value). Basically I want the blue spinner area be smaller(so we can see more of the gray background), but because of its variant being indeterminate We cannot change its value to reduce the circle's area.

Should I change its svg, and if so how?

```js
function Spinner(props){
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        position: 'relative',
      }}
    >
      <CircularProgress
        {...props}
        variant="determinate"
        size={40}
        thickness={4}
        value={100}
        sx={{
          color: (theme) =>
          theme.palette.grey[theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? 200 : 800],
        }}
      />
      <CircularProgress
        {...props}
        variant="indeterminate"
        size={40}
        thickness={4}
        disableShrink
        sx={{
          color: (theme) => (theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? '#1a90ff' : '#308fe8'),
          verticalAlign: "middle",
          animationDuration: '550ms',
          position: 'absolute',
          left: 0,
          [`& .${circularProgressClasses.circle}`]: {
            strokeLinecap: 'round',
          },
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code that you have so far. Makes the help more useful.

Comment: From the [documentation - CircularProgress API - Material UI](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/circular-progress/#props) it looks like (maybe) the variant should be `variant="determinate"` and then you can give the value `value={15}` or whatever. It is just like the gray circle that has `variant="determinate"` and `value="100"` for the full circle. Does that help?

Comment: Ty for your help @chrwahl, but one should be `indeterminate` cause you want it to be animated, I guess you can make both `determinate` then write a css animation for one but thats just unnecessary amount of svg for a simple spinner anyways I have wrote my own spinner I will make a pkg out of it and publish it in npm and put a link here if anyone wanted lightweight(in terms of KB) Facebook/Twitch like spinner which is compatible with MUI way of styling(emotion).